# AT CSQ returns CME error 604

Tags: microcontroller, gsm, sim900

I'm using an SIMCOM, SIM800. This module was working perfectly fine, but suddenly it stopped posting and while debugging I found out that AT+CSQ was returning "+CME **ERROR:604**" which according to Telit means **can not allocate control socket**

What does that mean? What does the control socket do? It's strange to see the CSQ command fail.
Design question
Has my power block somehow damaged the module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SIM800 module was non-functional. Once I changed all the AT commands worked perfectly fine. Thanks for the views. :)

Comment: Hello clamentjohn, i have the exact same problem with sending sms on sim800l module. Can you help me please and tell me what did you do to fix that?

Comment: @MohamedEssam My SIM800 was defective. I replaced it with a functional module and it worked as expected. See if you get the error response ERROR:604. If you do, try replacing the hardware and see if it works.